# SharedPreferences not save or whats wrong?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I´m trying to use SharedPreferences in a BroadcastReceiver to count how often onReceive is called. After 3 times the prefs saved value will be set to 0, also when the user starts the app, the value will be set to 0.

What works:
When the Receiver starts I can count and increment the value in the onReceive. When I call my Method cancelAlarm(), now with the context from the receiver, i can set the prefs value to 0.

What doesn't:
When the user opens the app, the prefs value should be set to 0, but I can't seem to set it with the activity context....

Receiver:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences homeCarePrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("HomeCare", 0);
        System.out.println("AlarmNotification.onRecive"+homeCarePrefs.getInt("count", 0));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = homeCarePrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", homeCarePrefs.getInt("count", 0)+1);
        editor.commit();

        if(homeCarePrefs.getInt("count", 0) >= 3){
            cancelAlarm(context);                                  //this works!!
        }

.....

       public void cancelAlarm(Context context){
            SharedPreferences homeCarePrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("HomeCare", 0);
            System.out.println("AlarmNotification.cancleAlarm "+homeCarePrefs.getInt("count", 0));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = homeCarePrefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("count", 0);
            editor.commit();
.....
```

Main

```html
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

  SharedPreferences homeCarePrefs = getSharedPreferences("HomeCare", 0);
        System.out.println("AlarmNotification.cancleAlarm "+homeCarePrefs.getInt("count", 0));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = homeCarePrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", 0);
        editor.commit();
  
  
  aN = new AlarmNotification();

   aN.cancelAlarm(this);
   aN.setAlarm(getApplicationContext(), person.getEvening());
```

Also, if I call cancelAlarm(this) from main it never sets the value to 0.

After 3 hours of trying I still can't understand why it's not working.

manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.SLFK.homecare"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="AlarmNotification"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="de.SLFK.homecare.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="screens.LoginScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="screens.MainScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="screens.WeightScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="screens.PulseScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="screens.SystolicScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="screens.DiastolicScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Tell your code you are calling it/

Comment: what exactly you mean. I call all in my main activity

Comment: You are just editing your shared preference value all the time. where you are trying to get after 3 hours?

Comment: sorry for my confusing english. I try to solve the problem by my selfe for 3 hours now i ask here. The problem is that the edit not work if i call it from main...

Comment: What exactly is not working, and how do you know it's not working?

Comment: Try to check your value for count right after resetting it in `onCreate` to check if its really not resetting. So after your `editor.commit()` you add `System.out.println(homeCarePrefs.getInt("count", 0))`

Comment: i have my reciever in this i count how often i call my onReceive. I have a outprint with the numer of count so i know its work. On the other side i have a main here i want to edit the same pref like in the reciever but in main i want set 0 also i have a outprint now my log ist for example : In Reciever (call 1) (call 2) (call 3) now i call in my main that i want set it to 0 my output in main is (call 0 ) now my output from recieve come and it say (call 4) so the edit in main not work but the output in main say it works....

Comment: Can you add your manifest?

Comment: omg 3 hours of work and i think its only becaus  android:process=":remote" >

Comment: Yes, you have to remove that from your manifest and then it should work.